# What happens if I buy a subscription on my iPad, but never open the app again or uninstall it and just use app via Android

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I am Working on a Multi-Platform Application. We have used stripe for subscription but the app is rejecting and forcing us to use IAP. now question is that how can we deal with this kind of Scenario like if a person buys a renewable Subscription through IAP or stripe or through google pay so how can we manage this.

- if a person buys a subscription on apple pay and he never uses that on ios and he uses that on android. and when the time to renew their subscription on android so he will get again the trial period.
  any Suggestion on this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not presenting a technical question, it's a matter of business choices.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation detail and policy decision for your business to make , keeping in mind the various platform application policies. You can create a new subscription with or without a trial for the same customer or a new customer. Perhaps you have unified accounts across platform, perhaps not. There's not really a technical obstacle here.